# Open files via links

Tags: php, html, file, hyperlink, local

Is it possible to open a file on local drive via html? I tried things as:
`<a href='filename.ext'>link</a>` for a file in the same map as the script. This works, but it downloads the file only (i use a mdb-file so it won't open in the webbrowser like an picture).

When i link to i.e. `<a href='file://c:\file.ext'>link</a>` or just without file:// nothing happens. Is it possible to link correctly to the files to open them and not just download them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not possible, unless the linking file is placed at the local disk. If you want to request a file from the user, for a form submission, use `<input type"file" />`.

Comment: If it were, it'd give me access to a whole host of information on your local drive that you wouldn't want me to see, so "No, it isn't"

Comment: It's possible, but with restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if it's on your machine.

What you have to do is register a protocol with the file extension you want to open.
In your case, **.mdb** would be MS Access database file.

If you want to click on a link in your browser and open the file in MS Access then you have to do the following:

```
<a href="your_protocol://c:\path\to\file.mdb">Open File</a>
```

Then you have to register "your_protocol" protocol with your computer.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\your_protocol]
@="URL:your_protocol Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\your_protocol\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\your_protocol\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\your_protocol\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Application\\program.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Replace "your_protocol" with arbitrary name of your choosing, edit the registry and link your files like in the example.

Answer (score 0):

No. 'Open' vs 'download' concerns the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header, returned by the server. When you open a local file, it is not coming from a web server, so you cannot change the headers / they do not exist.

Comment: Might there be another option to make it possible to open the file? or  at least get to the file by opening the folder where its located or?

Comment: My advice is don't do this at all. It is a bad idea to link to local files from a web site, end of story. How do you know that the file exists? How do you know where it is? The fact that this isn't possible to do hints at the fact that it isn't a good idea.

Comment: I got it working with the options of my webbrowser.. i.e. when u download files in chrome u have the option to always direct open the files from a specific extension. Because of the secured shell only this .bat file is ever downloaded. This means this batch file can execute the local file.

Comment: Well... I hope this site isn't public.

Comment: It's a local shell with only links available from specific sites.. A lot is locked so it won't be any problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the referring HTML document is on local drive, relative URLs will refer to local files, so e.g. `<a href='filename.ext'>link</a>` would refer to a file in the same folder. However, browsers will then get to HTTP headers that would specify the media type (such as text/html or image/gif), so they will need to apply some heuristics in guessing what to do with it, or to apply bindings in the system, or just offer a “Save As” dialog (the only thing a browser can really do without knowing or guessing the media type).

Typically, however, this will work as far as you use commonly know filename suffixes like .html or .gif.

If the referring document is on a server, things are different, but you can in theory refer to local files using the file: scheme , but its effect is completely system-dependent. The example `<a href='file://c:\file.ext'>link</a>` is syntactically malformed (though some browsers may accept it), since the backslash “\” is not allowed in a URL. Using `<a href='file://c:/file.ext'>link</a>` could in principle work, and it did work on early days of the Web, in case the user’s system happened to have a file that can be accessed with the pathname c:/file.ext (possibly mapped to c:\file.ext by the system).

But browsers have generally stopped supporting the file: scheme, presumably for assumed security reasons. Of course no information is directly sent to any server when a file: URL is used, but people thought it might be an indirect security threat. Moreover, file: URLs were of very limited usefulness from the beginning. (They were sometimes used in local networks to link to files on local network servers that do no act as HTTP servers.)